# Don't understand nested For Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I don't understand how the i in the 2nd for loop of the code below works.

```
di = [96, 15, 33, 87]
for i in range(len(di)):
    total = di[i]
    for j in range(i+1,len(di)):
        print(i)
0
0
0
1
1
2
```

Why is the output 0,0,0,1,1,2. How does i in the 2nd for loop get affected from the first loop? Is there some inheritance? Pardon the newbie here.

Comment: Try using a debugger to step through the program and take a look at the values of `i` and `j` at each step.

Comment: you are printing `i` inside the `j`-loop - `i` does not change inside of it. It is printed fewer times because the `j` loop gets shorter the bigger `i` gets.

Comment: There is is nothing specific to Python in this question. It's a general (newbie) programming question. Try printing (i, j) to see what is happening.

Comment: In Python you should generally avoid the range function. For instance, the outer for loop should be: `for total in di:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`len(di)` is 4. So the loop

```
for i in range(len(di)):
```

will repeat 4 times. Because of the way `range` works (from lower bound, which is 0 by default if not specified, to 1 below the upper bound), `i` will be `0` in the first repetition, `1` in the second repetition, and so on. To calculate out how many objects `range(x, y)` generates, in this case, how often `for i in range(x, y)`will repeat, you can simply do `number of repetitions = y - x`. So in this case: `len(di) - 0 (default lower bound) = 4`.

The loop

```
for j in range(i+1, len(di)):
    print(i)
```

will repeat the `print(i)` command `len(di) - (i + 1)` times. Keep in mind, `i` is defined by the outer loop. So, during the first loop of

```
for i in range(len(di)):
```

`i` equals `0`, so the `print(i)` command will be executed `4 - (0+1) = 3` times - it will print `i(=0)`  3 times. In the second loop, `i`equals 1, so it will be printed 2 times, and so on. So here's whats happening, formatted as code for better readability:

```
First outer loop: 
i = 0
total = di[i] = di[0] = 96
--> first inner loop of first outer loop:
    j = i + 1 = 1
    i is printed -> prints 0

    second inner loop of first outer loop:
    j = j+1 = 2
    i is printed -> prints 0 again

    third inner loop of first outer loop:
    j = j+1 = 3 --> since len(di) = 4, the upper bound of range(i+1, len(di)) is reached, so this is the last Repetition
    i is printed -> prints 0 again

Second outer loop:
i = 1
total = di[1] = 15
--> first inner loop of second outer loop:
    j = i+1 = 2
    i is printed -> prints 1

    second inner loop of second outer loop:
    j = i+1 = 3  -> upper bound of range reached, last repetition
    i is printed -> prints 1 again

Third outer loop:
i = 2
total = di[2] = 33
--> first inner loop of third outer loop:
    j = i+1 = 3  -> upper bound of range is reached, only Repetition
    i is printed -> prints 2

Fourth (and final) outer loop:
i = 3 -> upper bound of range(len(di)) reached, last Repetition
total = di[3] = 87
since j = i+1 = 4, the inner loop does not get executed at all (both bounds of range are equal), so 3 doesn't get printed

end of code.
```

Answer (score 0):

In programming language, a variable is available for usage within a scope. When you start for loop with a new variable then it would be available for usage until you end it.

As you are beginning the journey to learn python, one of the really good practice is to read official document. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `range`

Answer (score 0):

To help your understanding, try this:

```
di = [96, 15, 33, 87]
for i in range(len(di)):
    print("first loop, i =", i)
    total = di[i]
    for j in range(i+1,len(di)):
        print("second loop, j =", j)
        print("second loop, i =", i)
```

The i is the same in both loops. each time the outer loop runs, it then runs the inner loop until the "for" statement is complete.